# Bot return 0 in emulator

Tags: botframework

In my Dialog, I use below code to return message to customer:

```
var reply =  context.MakeMessage();
reply.Text = summary;
reply.Speak =  speak;
await context.PostAsync("tetsingtist");
await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

In Emulator,  Message is return correctly, "0" also return. **I do not know why there is one "0".**

[image]

Emulator version is **v3.5.36**

It will be great helpful if you can share your experience.

Thank you!

Comment: Based on your screenshot, `'0'` seems not rendered as a message, you can try to reinstall your bot emulator or use [Bot Framework Emulator V4](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases). Besides, I'd like to know if same issue appears when you connect to your another bot with emulator.

Comment: We had the same "0" appearing on the webchat when we sent messages with suggested actions without any text message

Comment: Nicolas, You are right. I use context.PostAsync to return empty text message in somewhere to get 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

In somewhere, I use `context.PostAsync` to return one empty text message to cause 0 in emulator.